# Does an IDisposable from IObservable.Subscribe() hold a reference to the source?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

Does an `IDisposable` from `IObservable.Subscribe()` hold a reference to the `IObservable`?

If the `IDisposable` is rooted and can't be garbage collected, does it hold a reference to the subscription and the `IObservable`?

In other words, if the intended lifetime of the `IObservable` is shorter than the lifetime of the returned `IDisposable`, can the `IObservable` be GC'ed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. It doesn't have to, but it very well could.

Comment: The tests that Enigmativity and I created verify your answer. The rule of thumb appears to be: Assume the IDisposable does hold a reference, unless you've explicitly tested your implementation to show that it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I created some quick test code for this, and it seems that the `IDisposable` will keep a reference and hold the `IObservable` in memory.  Or at least very well could, as Jason says.

```
Subject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();
WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(subject);

IDisposable disposable = subject.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Next: " + i));

subject.OnNext(5);
subject.OnNext(10);
subject = null;

GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive ? "Subject is still alive." : "Subject is not alive.");
```

When written as above, the weak reference will still be alive. If I comment out the disposable assignment, then `subject` gets GC'ed.

```
/*IDisposable disposable = */ subject.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Next: " + i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test that seems to show that the observable is GC'ed:

```
var xs = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
var disposable = xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

var wr = new WeakReference(xs);
xs = null;

Thread.Sleep(2000);

Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive); // True

GC.Collect();

Console.WriteLine(wr.IsAlive); // False
```

Comment: Interesting, that's opposite the result I got when testing with Subject<>.  I ran your code and verified your results.

It seems Jason's answer is correct, it depends on the implementation you're subscribing to.